# How do I use try-catch correctly in simple methods?

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to make sure my classes are robust - even if they are simple and seem dumb to an experienced programmer.

Let's say I have a method as written below that accepts a string[] and returns it as an int[].

```
public static int[] GetIntArrayFromStringArray(string[] stringArray)
    {
        int i = 0;
        int[] ints = new int[stringArray.Length];
        foreach (var str in stringArray)
        {
            ints[i++] = (str != "" ? int.Parse(str) : 0);
        }
        return ints;
    }
```

Is the best option to use try-catch and throw an exception?  When I try to use try-catch, it seems to have issues with my variables not being in scope but I need them to be in a try-catch to catch any errors with the stringArray being null!

Perhaps I should use this?

```
    if (stringArray == null) //do something ...
```

but not sure what to do in the event of an error ... do I return a null int[] or throw exception?

*(I also have to check that the int.Parse(str) doesn't fail - I'm getting to that one but hoped it could be in the try-catch block!)*

As I said, these are simple tasks that I want to try and get correct now before I develop too many bad habits.  Thanks.

Comment: Declare your variables above the try statement

Comment: @AlexR, what do you mean by expensive - memory wise?

Comment: @JohnnBlade - I need to test the stringArray to ensure it was not null ... looking like try-catch is not my best option for this type of thing.

Comment: Fixed it for you, see my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public static int[] GetIntArrayFromStringArray(string[] stringArray)
    {
        if (stringArray == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("stringArray");
        }

        int count = stringArray.Length;
        int[] ints = new int[count];
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            int intValue;
            ints[i] = int.TryParse(stringArray[i], out intValue) ? intValue : 0;
        }
        return ints;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use int.TryParse() instead.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx

Answer (score 1):

1. If *stringArray* is null, immediately throw a *NullArgumentException*.
2. Try something simpler for the conversion:

   return stringArray.Select(s => IntParseOrDefault(s, 0)).ToArray();

Where *IntParseOrDefault* is just like this:

```
int IntParseOrDefault(string s, int defaultVal)
{
    int i;
    if (!int.TryParse(s, out i)) i = defaultVal;
    return i;
}
```

If you want the method to fail if *any* of the strings is not a valid integer, then instead of using a default value, throw an *InvalidArgumentException* when *TryParse* fails.

Comment: okay, so you do throw Exceptions but do them specifically instead of the "try-catch".

Comment: @Sisyphus yes, there's no need for try-catch blocks in this method, because there's no uncertainty (like there would be for a database or network call, etc).  You can validate the input, and if it's invalid, either accept it or throw an exception back to the caller.

Answer (score 0):

Here an example

```
        foreach (string str in stringArray)
        {
            int nr = 0;
            int.TryParse(str, out nr);

            if (nr > 0)
                ints[i++] = nr;
        }
```

here is the full code

```
public static int[] GetIntArrayFromStringArray(string[] stringArray)
{
    if (stringArray == null || stringArray.Length == 0)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("string array is null or empty");

    int i = 0;
    int[] ints = new int[stringArray.Length];
    foreach (var str in stringArray)
    {
        int nr = 0;
        int.TryParse(str, out nr);
        if (nr > 0)
            ints[i] = nr;
        i++;
    }
    return ints;
}
```

Comment: what happens when the str is "0" - doesn't this skip the index and leave it null?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can use try - catch:

```
public static int[] GetIntArrayFromStringArray(string[] stringArray)
{
    int i = 0;
    int[] ints = null;
    try {
        ints = new int[stringArray.Length];
        foreach (var str in stringArray)
        {
            ints[i++] = (str != "" ? int.Parse(str) : 0);
        }
    }
    catch {
         // Throw custom exception
    }
return ints;
}
```

Comment: the compiler doesn't like this ... Error: Use of unassigned local variable 'ints'

Answer (score 0):

I would throw a custom-exception in the catch-block. So the user of your class can catch for this exception.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int[] GetIntArrayFromStringArray(string[] stringArray)
    {
        int i = 0;
        int[] ints;
        int num;
        if (stringArray == null && stringArray.Length > 0)
        {
        ints = new int[stringArray.Length]
        foreach (var str in stringArray)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str) && int.TryParse(str, num))
            {
            ints[i++] = num;
            }  
        }
        }
        return ints;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Many methods in the .NET Framework that throw exceptions on invalid input have non-throwing counterparts, usually prefixed with `Try`, that return a boolean value instead.  For instance, in the case of `int.Parse`, you'll have an easier time calling `int.TryParse`, e.g.:

```
public static int[] GetIntArrayFromStringArray(string[] stringArray)
{
    int i = 0;
    int[] ints = new int[stringArray.Length];
    foreach (var str in stringArray)
    {
        int a = 0
        int.TryParse(str, out a)
        ints[i++] = a;
    }
    return ints;
}
```